# Looking for efficiency here

Tags: shell

So I have a fairly simple, but terribly written script to recursively search directories, extract .zips in them to the folder they sit in and do a basic error check and cleanup on extracted files.  For the record, my complete lack of competence is well illustrated by that business with creating a file as a flag to get information out of the while read pipe structure.  It's honestly just what came to mind quickly it worked from the first try and doesn't actually leave file clutter so I left it alone.  I've really got no experience with scripting and not much in general beyond playing around with C++, but am working on this to get a feel for scripting the shell to practical ends.  The problem is that even I can see that there is nothing elegant about how I've done this, and moreover the search takes a very long time (far longer than going into and listing the directories would on its own) and I really don't know what's slowing it down.

I can see that unzip is being called at least a couple of times per file, but it's less a question of lots of .zips than lots of folders with lots of files.  Is there something simple I've missed in terms of cleaning this up, or am I just running into the realities of the file system (at this point it was faster to do this procedure semi manually with search and extract on windows than to automate on linux*)?  Would a better option be just to accept that this is going to take significant time, make it run in the background and dump all the output to a log?

In any case, if you want to wade into this, the full code for my unzipr script is below.

```
echo "" >> unzipr.log
echo "----" >> unzipr.log
echo " " >> unzipr.log
find . -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do 
    dir=$(dirname $filename)
    unzip -nqq "$filename" -d "$dir"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then 
        rm $filename
        echo "$filename succesfully extracted"
    else
        #unzip -t "$filename"
        echo "Error in $filename"
        echo $filename >> unzipr.log
        failed=true
        echo >> unzipr.fail
    fi ;
done
if [ -e unzipr.fail ] ; then
    echo "EXTRACTION ERRRORS DETECTED"
    rm unzipr.fail
    exit 1
else
    echo "Extraction successful"
    exit 0
fi
```

*it just occurred to me that I was taking advantage of windows search indexing with those searches...  I may have to go back to the drawing board here, no idea off hand how to do something equivalent with Linux in the first place, let alone automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Given the initial `echo` lines, the `if [ -e unzipr.fail ]` test is always going to be true (the file will exist), so you will report that extraction errors were detected.

Comment: You don't need to loop through all the zip files in case you hit an error.  Not sure what else you imply by efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no room for serious optimizations. The logic of your script is pretty straightforward. Theoretically you can unzip files in parallel and cleanup failed files than however, I believe there will be no significant difference in performance.

So my fix is trivial, unzipr.fail file is superfluous here

```
echo "" >> unzipr.log
echo "----" >> unzipr.log
echo " " >> unzipr.log
find . -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do 
    dir=$(dirname $filename)
    unzip -nqq "$filename" -d "$dir"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then 
        rm $filename
        echo "$filename succesfully extracted"
    else
        #unzip -t "$filename"
        echo "Error in $filename"
        echo $filename >> unzipr.log
        failed=true
    fi ;
done
if [ "$failed" ] ; then
    echo "EXTRACTION ERRRORS DETECTED"
    rm unzipr.fail
    exit 1
else
    echo "Extraction successful"
    exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of files, I guess that a lot of overhead is done because you use the shell. You launch a lot of processes: dirname, unzip, rm. If you run the command "top", I guess you will see a lot of system load: The operating system needs to start too many processes.

I use the shell daily since 17 years, but for scripts like this I use python.